Improving Similarity Measurement of Event Dates in Sentence Transformer Models
I'm developing a system to compute the similarity between textual descriptions of events using the sentence-transformers library. Despite trying various models, I am particularly struggling to capture significant changes in similarity scores when the date or time information in these descriptions changes. The best results so far have been with the multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1 model, but even with this model, changes in dates affect the similarity scores less significantly compared to other details like the event name or location.
Event Name: Global Tech Symposium 2024
Event Date: 25th August 2024
Event Type: Technology Conference

Event Details:

Hosted by the Institute of Advanced Technology, the event tenure is from timestamp: No Information Available to timestamp: 1725148800.0.
Held at the Convention Centre, Silicon Valley, the planning phase began from timestamp: No Information Available to timestamp: 1700764800.0.
Keynote sessions delivered by experts from leading tech companies, sessions commenced from timestamp: 1725052400.0 to timestamp: 1725235200.0.

I need the model to reflect significant differences when dates or times are changed in the event descriptions. Currently, altering event names or locations results in substantial changes in similarity scores, but modifying dates—even to completely different timestamps—has minimal impact.
Attempts:
Tested various formats for representing date and time (YYYY-MM-DD, full date in words, Unix timestamps).
Experimented with numerous transformer models to find one that best captures the impact of date changes:

all-MiniLM-L6-v2
all-mpnet-base-v2
multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1
all-distilroberta-v1
all-MiniLM-L12-v2
multi-qa-distilbert-cos-v1
paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2
paraphrase-albert-small-v2
paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2
paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2
distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v1
distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v2

Among these, multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1 yielded the most favorable results, but still not to a satisfactory level.
Question:
How can I better represent date and time information in sentence similarity calculations to ensure these details significantly affect the similarity scores? Are there specific configurations or other transformer models known to be more sensitive to temporal data changes that I should consider?
